# TYPO3 Form finisher redirect to anchor link

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I set up a form with the form BE module in TYPO3 8.7.10 and added a finisher to redirect the user to a thank-you page after successfully submitting the form. That works fine but I`d like to add an anchor-link parameter so that the user will see a special content element with the ID #c155 on the target page.
So I added #c155 to the additional parameter field of the redirect finisher but it doesn`t work as the resulting redirect URL is something like:
http://test.test/formpage/thankyou/?L=0&%23c155=#identifier

How can I enable the redirect to a certain anchor?

Thanks you.

```
finishers:
-
options:
subject: 'Subject'
  recipientAddress: admin@test.test
  recipientName: 'Admin Receiver'
  senderAddress: '{text-2}'
  senderName: '{firstname} {name}'
  replyToAddress: ''
  carbonCopyAddress: ''
  blindCarbonCopyAddress: nsa@test.test
  format: plaintext
  attachUploads: false
  translation:
    language: ''
identifier: EmailToReceiver
```

-
    options:
      pageUid: '49'
      additionalParameters: '#c155'
    identifier: Redirect

Comment: I have the same problem. Are you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Anchor targets are no real URL parameter, so you might be mislead to use additionalParameters. (In TYPO3) they belong to the base of the URL, here: `pageUid`.

The other way would be to trick the parameter handling. Just append the anchor to the last real parameter value. And you might need to insert a dummy parameter: `dummy=1#c155`

Comment: thank you. The workaround with the dummy param seems to work in some browsers but not on Android handys. I had a look at sysext/form/Classes/Domain/Finishers/RedirectFinisher.php and it seems a section parameter for the typolink function is missing. Maybe the selection dialogue for the target page should be designed like Link Browser of the RTE. Then one could select not only pages but also content elements.

Comment: @SachaVorbeck ...do you have an answer to your question?

Comment: @TYPO3UA no but maybe you can do a workaround by redirecting to a page of type external url and add the anchor to the target URL there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I saw your request on the  https://forge.typo3.org/issues/83912 ... I talked with guys about it on the slack.com ... They said that "...i think we should tackle it in january. imho it is a feature. but we will discuss the backport...." and that will be discussed or it is a bug or it is a new feature "...we will discuss it. if we declare it as bug -> yes, if we declare it as feature -> no. right now i think it is a feature. but we will see as soon as we've built it..."